# To Iterate through all layers and all attributes for each layer

Tags: pyqgis, layers, fields-attributes, iteration, qgis-python-console

I am working in the Python console in QGIS 3.10. I want to iterate through all layers and for each layer iterate through all attributes and set them all to 'Hidden'.

I want to do this in preparation for creating a webmap using a plugin. The data sets I am using have come from various places - GSI, BGS, OSI, EMODNet - and there are a lot of attribute fields in the 14 layers.
I am new to Python and have managed to list the layer names in the console, but am failing to loop through the attributes - I keep getting attribute values - thousands of them.

Can anyone help explain how I can get to list the attribute names and thereby amend their widget to 'Hidden'?

```py
project = QgsProject.instance()
for id , layer in project.mapLayers().items():
    for field in layer.fields():
        print(layer.name() , field.name())
```

OK, not to worry, I found the answer.

The following code worked,

```
project = QgsProject.instance()
for id , layer in project.mapLayers().items():
    for field in layer.fields():
        print(layer.name() , field.name())
        idx = layer.fields().indexFromName(field.name())
        setup = QgsEditorWidgetSetup('Hidden', {})
        layer.setEditorWidgetSetup(idx, setup)
```

This question was cancelled because it was deemed off topic, which I don't get, but never mind.

Comment: You should add the code you have to date that loops the attribute values.